# Can I do left join from two table from one SQL Server database and one table from another database?

Tags: sql-server

If it's possible can someone show me with this example?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.SheetID,
    IF.MOTHER,
    IF.FATHER,
    IF.SON,
    IF.DAUGHTER,
    FM.GRANDFATHER,
    FM.GRANDMOTHER, 
    FM.UNCLE,
    FM.AUNT
FROM 
    Family.dbo.family IF
LEFT JOIN 
    Family.dbo.fatherandmothersiderelatives FM ON S.SheetID = FM.FamilyID
LEFT JOIN 
    FammilyFiles.dbo.[Sheet] S ON S.SheetID = IF.FamilyID
```

Comment: What did you try? Do you have any problems with your query?

Comment: Yes.  The multi-part identifier ".FamilyID" could not be bound.

Comment: IF is a SQL keyword... try enclosing it in square brackets (like you did with "Sheet").

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you need to join tables in the order they're referenced. In your example `Family.dbo.fatherandmothersiderelatives FM ON S.SheetID = FM.FamilyID` refers to `Sheet s` before it's been joined and aliased (and you should get an error like *The multi-part identifier "S.SheetID" could not be bound.*). You need to change the order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.SheetID,
    [IF].MOTHER,
    [IF].FATHER,
    [IF].SON,
    [IF].DAUGHTER,
    FM.GRANDFATHER,
    FM.GRANDMOTHER, 
    FM.UNCLE,
    FM.AUNT
FROM 
    Family.dbo.family [IF]
LEFT JOIN 
    Family.dbo.[Sheet] S ON S.SheetID = [IF].FamilyID
LEFT JOIN 
    FamilyFiles.dbo.fatherandmothersiderelatives FM ON S.SheetID = FM.FamilyID
```

Also `IF`is a reserved keyword and as such is a really bad choice for a table alias - if you really want to use it you can enclose it in brackets like above.